# is their a way to clone latest tag instead of cloning master everytime

Tags: git, shell, github, github-actions

> is their any way to clone latest tag instead of cloning branch every time and without using any shell script.
> Like we can use direct cli.

Comment: Sounds like a plan. What did you try so far?

Comment: Git clones the whole repository. It up to you to checkout whatever revision you need after cloning.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Once you have *a* clone, it should just be a matter of *fetching* any new tags from the remote.

Comment: so @RomainValeri : i have created a shell script which will record the latest value of release tag created and will update the checkout model to checkout only the latest release tag .... i dont feel it is fesible for every time...i have searched multiple forums and need an confirmation that if we have simple one liner of git command that clones branch instead of master

Comment: @mouviciel : so lets see the example here 
library identifier: 'jenkins-sharedlib@master', retriever : modernSCM([$class: 'GitSCMSource',
  remote : 'https://github.com/multiple-docs/jenkins-sharedlib.git',
  credentialsId : 'jenkinsCreds'])
so this will clone master branch of sharedlib every time ....so lets belive that this library has release tag created ...for examole v.1.0.0 ...so i am trying to clone this tag i mean latest tag instead of master branch

Comment: @chepner : you can check my condition of importing

Comment: like refs/tags/latest

Comment: in  library identifier: 'jenkins-sharedlib@v.1.0', retriever : modernSCM([$class: 'GitSCMSource', remote : 'github.com/multiple-docs/jenkins-sharedlib.git', credentialsId : 'jenkinsCreds']) 
this will work ,but we need to update the tag version everytime manually ..so i am looking for the latest tag should be cloned

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
git clone -b <tag> --single-branch <url>
```

If you don't need the whole history, create a shallow clone with `--depth <n>` (which implies `--single-branch`)

```
git clone -b <tag> --depth 1 <url>
```

Comment: i want release tag to be cloned and should not mention every time

Comment: like refs/tags/latest